# Can't link against mongocxx static libraries

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

I have install mongocxx's both static and dynamic libraries.

```
$ l /usr/local/lib/libmongoc* 
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so@    /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0  /usr/local/lib/libmongocxx.so@       /usr/local/lib/libmongocxx.so._noabi@
/usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0@  /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-static-1.0.a  /usr/local/lib/libmongocxx.so.3.8.0  /usr/local/lib/libmongocxx-static.a
$ l /usr/local/lib/libbson*
/usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so@    /usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0  /usr/local/lib/libbsoncxx.so.3.8.0    /usr/local/lib/libbsoncxx-static.a
/usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0@  /usr/local/lib/libbsoncxx.so@        /usr/local/lib/libbsoncxx.so._noabi@  /usr/local/lib/libbson-static-1.0.a
```

Despite giving full path to static libraries of mongocxx using `target_link_libraries`, I keep getting this error:

```
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5e): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6d): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::core(bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x91): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::key_view(core::v1::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb5): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::append(bsoncxx::v_noabi::types::b_string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xc2): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::extract_document()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xca): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::~core()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe8): undefined reference to `bsoncxx::v_noabi::builder::core::~core()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xf2): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::~instance()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x112): undefined reference to `mongocxx::v_noabi::instance::~instance()'
```

I've added the following `find_package`s commands

```
find_package(mongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(bsoncxx REQUIRED)
find_package(mongoc-1.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(mongoc-1.0 REQUIRED)
find_package(bson-1.0 REQUIRED)
```

and added the libraries to `target_link_libraries` as follows:

```
    INTERFACE mongo::mongocxx_static
    INTERFACE mongo::bsoncxx_static
    INTERFACE mongo::bson_static
    INTERFACE mongo::mongoc_static
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm trying to build a static executable.

Comment: Your problem is in how you use cmake [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html#target-link-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared these dependencies as `INTERFACE`, which indicates that the target itself doesn't depend on them, but that dependencies of the target do. As a result, those libraries are not being included in the link for your target, since it doesn't depend on them.

If you intend for your target to actually make use of these libraries, they should be added as `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` to your target.

Comment: To clarify; [`PUBLIC`: your target and targets that depend on your target can use them. `PRIVATE`: only your target can use them.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html#target-link-libraries)